# Play Video/Audio on HTML View from Database on all Browser MVC

Tags: html, model-view-controller, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I am doing a project that retrieves audio/video from database in varbinary(max). I already have a code that could play audio/video from database but it is only working on IE. But I want to make this mvc project to be able to play video/audio across all browser if possible.

Here is code on View:

```
 <object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="320" height="310">
                    <param name="filename" value="@Url.Action("FileToPlay","Home", new { CallRowID = Model.RowID })">
                    <param name="animationatstart" value="true">
                    <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
                    <param name="autostart" value="true">
                    <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
                    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
                    <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
                    <embed src="@Url.Action("FileToPlay","Home", new { CallRowID = Model.RowID })" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="1" bgcolor="white" width="320" height="310" />
                </object>
```

Code on Controller

```cs
        public ActionResult FileToPlay(string CallRowID)
        {
            Guid callguid = Guid.Parse(CallRowID);

            byte[] bytes;
            string contentType;
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultContext"].ConnectionString;
            string name;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select Top 1 * from FileTable where RowID=@Id";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", callguid);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["VideoByte"];
                    contentType = sdr["VideoMimeType"].ToString();
                    name = sdr["VideoFileName"].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            var memorystream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            return new FileStreamResult(memorystream, contentType);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Object embeds for HTML audio/video have long since been outmoded, in favor of `<audio>` and `<video>` elements.

You might try something like this:

```
<video autoplay controls>
  <source src="@Url.Action("FileToPlay","Home", new { CallRowID = Model.RowID })" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

(Note, you'll want to fill in the correct MIME type as well.  I'm just assuming MP4 here.)